# Gitlab-ci can not substitute variable in a bash script while running SSH command

Tags: shell, ssh, terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run a pipeline in which I need to start proxying through a bastion server. To do this, I have a seperate .sh file where I first fetch the IP of Bastion server;

```
bastion_public_ip=$(cd ${ROOT_PATH}/infrastructure/bastion; terraform init || return; terraform output bastion_public_ip)
```

then I try to establish proxy:

```
echo $bastion_public_ip
ssh -C -N -D 19990 -4 -i ${SSH_DIR}/bastion centos@${bastion_public_ip}
```

However it somehow tries to re-initizalize terraform folder and does not substitute the variable. What would potential cause be?

Here is the output:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname \033[0m\033[1minitializing: Name does not resolve
```

Comment: What does the output look like? Can you also edit the question to include the relevant job definition from your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as well please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have edited both question and title so that you can have a look at the output. It is a bit weird to me.

Comment: That looks like your init is failing so it's putting the output from `terraform init` into your `bastion_public_ip` variable. You should probably try to debug that by splitting out the commands.